# C# sort a dictionary by value

Tags: c#

I am sorting a dictionary, consisting of values & keys  , by value.  I have a hash of words and number of time used, that I want to order by number of time used.

There is a SortedList which is good for a single value , that I want to map it back to the word.

SortedDictionary orders by key, not value.

I could use a custom class,  is there a better way.

I did some google searches but I can't find exactly what I am lookign for.

Comment: `Dictionary` is not sorted, by design. There is no sense in sorting it. How are you going to use it? Show the practical example and we will try to find the most optimal collection \ solution.

Comment: You need to copy your dictionary (which is by definition, unsorted) into some other collection (for example, a list), then sort the second collection.  Look at the .Net method [.toList()](http://www.dotnetperls.com/tolist)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> BillsList = aDictionary.ToList();

BillsList.Sort(delegate(KeyValuePair<string, string> firstPair,
    KeyValuePair<string, string> nextPair)
    {
        return firstPair.Value.CompareTo(nextPair.Value);
    }
);
```

Comment: You can use lambda to make its simpler. `BillsList.Sort((firstPair, nextPair) => firstPair.Value.CompareTo(nextPair.Value));`

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
Dictionary<string, string> d = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
  {"A","Z"},
  {"B","Y"},
  {"C","X"}
};

d.OrderBy(x=>x.Value).Select(x=>x.Key);
```

Will return C, B, A.

Answer (score 2):

Here is using Linq and mapping the Count to the Word:

```
IDictionary<string, int> wordsAndCount = new Dictionary<string, int>
{
    {"Batman", 987987987},
    {"MeaningOfLife",42},
    {"Fun",69},
    {"Relaxing",420},
    {"This", 2}
};

var result = wordsAndCount.OrderBy(d => d.Value).Select(d => new 
{
   Word = d.Key,
   Count = d.Value
});
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Excellent choice of example key-value pairs